# TKinter problem with getting return values out of Entry from GUI Designer

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, return-value

First off: I am an absolute noob. I am currently trying to write a simple GUI with tkinter and I fail horribly. Most of the code below is written by an GUI designer and not by me. Maybe I would´ve been much faster if I did it myself. Most tutorials go other ways or go with Pyhton 2, so I just don´t know how to fix this damn thing.

What the program is supposed to do: This thing is meant to become a GUI for a ... Batch Script. This script takes a Source and a Target Path, filters certain File Extensions and copies them from A to B while leaving anything else alone. This GUI is supposed to provide the Data to it. Enter Source, enter target press start and the batch script starts to party hard.

The problem I have is this: My Python GUI isn´t able to even echo the variables after the button is pressed. I exactly know where the problem is but after many tries I just can´t figure out how to manage it. It is the GiveTarget.get() and GiveSource.get() along with the StartButton_command function. (Commented it out)

```
    import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import subprocess
import os

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        
        

        GiveSource=tk.Entry(root)
        GiveSource["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GiveSource["font"] = ft
        GiveSource["fg"] = "#333333"
        GiveSource["justify"] = "left"
        GiveSource.place(x=110,y=50,width=328,height=30)
        global x
        x = GiveSource.get() #####This is wrong!#####
        
        GiveTarget=tk.Entry(root)
        GiveTarget["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GiveTarget["font"] = ft
        GiveTarget["fg"] = "#333333"
        GiveTarget["justify"] = "left"
        GiveTarget.place(x=110,y=120,width=327,height=30)
        global y
        y = GiveTarget.get() #####This is also wrong!#####

        
        StartButton=tk.Button(root)
        StartButton["activebackground"] = "#90ee90"
        StartButton["activeforeground"] = "#ffffff"
        StartButton["bg"] = "#5fb878"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        StartButton["font"] = ft
        StartButton["fg"] = "#000000"
        StartButton["justify"] = "center"
        StartButton["text"] = "Start"
        StartButton.place(x=110,y=180,width=323,height=44)
        StartButton["command"] = self.StartButton_command

       



   

    def StartButton_command(self): #"Start" Button
    
        print("Start")
        
        print ("Source=" + x)
        print ("Target=" + y)
        
        print ("called HDD Copy")
        #subprocess.Popen([r'HDD_Kopierer.bat'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the widgets available throughout the App class by using self when you create them.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import subprocess
import os

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.GiveSource=tk.Entry(root)
        self.GiveSource["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        self.GiveSource["font"] = ft
        self.GiveSource["fg"] = "#333333"
        self.GiveSource["justify"] = "left"
        self.GiveSource.place(x=110,y=50,width=328,height=30)
  
        self.GiveTarget=tk.Entry(root)
        self.GiveTarget["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        self.GiveTarget["font"] = ft
        self.GiveTarget["fg"] = "#333333"
        self.GiveTarget["justify"] = "left"
        self.GiveTarget.place(x=110,y=120,width=327,height=30)

        
        StartButton=tk.Button(root)
        StartButton["activebackground"] = "#90ee90"
        StartButton["activeforeground"] = "#ffffff"
        StartButton["bg"] = "#5fb878"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        StartButton["font"] = ft
        StartButton["fg"] = "#000000"
        StartButton["justify"] = "center"
        StartButton["text"] = "Start"
        StartButton.place(x=110,y=180,width=323,height=44)
        StartButton["command"] = self.StartButton_command


    def StartButton_command(self): #"Start" Button
    

        print("Start")
        
        print ("Source=" + self.GiveSource.get())
        print ("Target=" + self.GiveTarget.get())
        
        print ("called HDD Copy")
        #subprocess.Popen([r'HDD_Kopierer.bat'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```